# What's the correct way to deal with a file name refactor in a Python package for backwards compatibility?

Tags: python, version-control

Say I have a file called `A.py` and for whatever reason I decided to consolidate it and some other files into `B.py`

Users previously did `from A import func`. What's the correct way to handle this while keeping backwards compatibility?

I was considering keeping `A.py` and in there, putting `from .B import func`

Comment: Note: If an answer is: "we would never do this - just increment version number and tell users it's changed" that's fine. Confirmation will be helpful.

Comment: in `__init__.py` file import B and then set A=B

Comment: @sahasrara62 let's say B takes on functionality from C and D as well. That wouldn't work then right?

Comment: I think keeping `A.py` and in there, putting `from .B import func` is fine, however you might also add a deprecation warning to it, that decribes that users should use module `B` in the future.

Comment: @PéterLeéh thanks. good suggestion

Comment: it will work, you need to consider that when calling file B as A from external folder, you can do as `from folder import A` this will work, but if you do `from folder.A import xyz` this won't and in internal same folder calling you need to use B as name.